# Get rowIndex of rich:dataTable rows

Tags: jsf, datatable

In my JSF application, I use a rich:dataTable as follows:

```
<rich:dataTable id="itemTable" value="#{backingBean.itemsList}" var="i" >
    <rich:column>   <f:facet name="header">ItemValue</f:facet>
        <h:inputText id="myId" value="#{i.value}" style="width: 30px" />
    </rich:column> </rich:dataTable>

<h:commandButton id="saveB" value="Save" action="#{backingBean.doSave()}" />
```

Bean code of doSave:

```
public String doSave() {
     Iterator<Item> = itemsList.iterator();
     while(iter.hasNext()) {
         //do something
     }
}
```

In the doSave()-Method, i need to know the row index of the current Item, is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

While Richfaces extended data tables support a [selection management](http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=extendedDataTable&sample=exTableSelection&skin=blueSky), Richfaces datatables don't.

What I found the easiest way to do to retrieve a somehow selected item from a list, is to add an icon to every row. For this, put the command-Button into the data table itself:

```
<rich:dataTable id="itemTable" value="#{backingBean.itemsList}" var="i" >
    <rich:column>   
        <h:inputText id="myId" value="#{i.value}" />
        <h:commandButton id="saveB" action="#{backingBean.doSave}" />
    </rich:column>
</rich:dataTable>
```

In the bean code, provide the method `doSave` but with an additional parameter ´ActionEvent´

```
public String doSave(ActionEvent ev) {
    Item selectedItem = null;
    UIDataTable objHtmlDataTable = retrieveDataTable((UIComponent)ev.getSource());

    if (objHtmlDataTable != null) {
        selectedItem = (Item) objHtmlDataTable.getRowData();
    }
}

private static UIDataTable retrieveDataTable(UIComponent component) {
    if (component instanceof UIDataTable) {return (UIDataTable) component;}
    if (component.getParent() == null) {return null;}
    return retrieveDataTable(component.getParent());
}
```

You see, that the `ActionEvent ev` provides you with the source element `(UIComponent)ev.getSource()`. Traverse through it until you hit the `UIDataTable` element and use it's row data.

Possible way two is to justgive the element as parameter with the function call:

```
 <rich:dataTable id="itemTable" value="#{backingBean.itemsList}" var="i" >
    <rich:column>   
        <h:inputText id="myId" value="#{i.value}" />
        <h:commandButton id="saveB" action="#{backingBean.doSave(i)}" />
    </rich:column>
</rich:dataTable>
```

and in the bean

```
public String doSave(Item item) {
  // do stuff
}
```

That's not as clean, but should work with the EL, too. Hope, it helps...

Comment: @Mr.Radar Did that solution help you in any way?